# oracle find the timestamp with max value from multiple tables with same columns

Tags: sql, oracle, select, database-design, plsql

i have 4 tables with similar set of columns.

Table 1:

```
a1 b1 c1 timestamp1
```

Table 2:

```
a2 b2 c2 timestamp2
```

Table 3:

```
a3 b3 c3 timestamp3
```

Table 4:

```
a4 b4 c4 timestamp4
```

Result i need will be like, timestamp value of the max value of column(c1,c2,c3,c4) from all the 4 tables.

Comment: if you are using Oracle you don't should tag mysql  ... tag removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `union all` to simulate a single table with all columns, and then take the row with the maximal timestamp:

```
SELECT a, b, c, timestamp
FROM   (SELECT a, b, c, timestmap, 
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY timestamp DESC) AS rn
        FROM   (SELECT a1 AS a, b1 AS b, c1 AS c, timestamp FROM table1
                UNION ALL
                SELECT a2 AS a, b2 AS b, c2 AS c, timestamp FROM table2
                UNION ALL
                SELECT a3 AS a, b3 AS b, c3 AS c, timestamp FROM table3
                UNION ALL
                SELECT a4 AS a, b4 AS b, c4 AS c, timestamp FROM table4))
         WHERE rn = 1
```

Alternatively, if you're using Oracle 12c, you could use the more elegant `fetch first` syntax:

```
SELECT   a, b, c, timestamp
FROM     (SELECT a1 AS a, b1 AS b, c1 AS c, timestamp FROM table1
          UNION ALL
          SELECT a2 AS a, b2 AS b, c2 AS c, timestamp FROM table2
          UNION ALL
          SELECT a3 AS a, b3 AS b, c3 AS c, timestamp FROM table3
          UNION ALL
          SELECT a4 AS a, b4 AS b, c4 AS c, timestamp FROM table4)
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
```

Comment: I love the new 12c fetch first row only syntax.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the max value out of column C from each table. We can simply use MAX functon on each table then a union and again a MAX to get the result. Hope this one also suffice your requirement.

```
SELECT MAX(COL) FROM
(SELECT MAX(C1) COL FROM  TABLE1
UNION ALL
SELECT MAX(C2) FROM  TABLE2
UNION ALL
SELECT MAX(C3) FROM  TABLE3
UNION ALL
SELECT MAX(C4) FROM  TABLE4
);
```